# Sequelize update with associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models which user and merchant. I will send JSON data from UI.
In Sequelize, I have used "include" option to insert the data like below.

```
models.user.create(req.body, { include: [models.merchant] });
```

It is working well as expected. So I have tried to update the data like below.

```
var filter = {
            where: { id: id },
            include: [
                models.merchant
            ]
        };

models.user.update(req.body, filter);
```

The above code is updating user data only. Association is not working in the update. I don't know what is wrong with this.

Please anyone help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour your asking for simply can't be done with a single update call. If you check [the docs for the update function](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update), there isn't an include option, i.e. sequelize can only build an update query for the table of the model who's update function is called.

You will have to update the associations separately. I advise that you put those updates inside a transaction to avoid any issues with multiple updates to the same object happening at the same time.

Comment: @ErnestJones I didn't test this out, but since the [docs for upsert](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert) say _"Insert or update a single row"_ and there is no mention of FKs and aggregate objects, I'm not sure it would update a linked subobject. My guess that `upsert` has roughly the same implementation as `update` for its update use case